# Is there any way to store my API keys? - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension, and have an API call that requires tokens. Is there any way to hide these tokens?

Comment: "Is there any way to hide these tokens?" - From whom or what?

Comment: They just shouldn't be shared publicly.

Comment: Host the API call-related stuff on a server.

Comment: There's no way. The local user can use devtools to inspect anything stored/calculated locally.